# IFilter Textreader not working within IIS/ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, pdf, docx, ifilter, textreader

I need to extract text from DOC, DOCX and PDF files.

I've downloaded two Windows Forms Application demo projects, one here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31944/Implementing-a-TextReader-to-extract-various-files

the other here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13391/Using-IFilter-in-C

Both are working just fine within the windows Form Application. But both do not work within my ASP.NET MVC2 application, it gets saying it can't find a filter or throws a method not implemented exception.

Could this be a security error? Like ASP.NET cannot reach the various IFilter's installed on the machine.

DOC files are working by the way.

All is x64 and the files are first saved on disk and have the proper permissions set.

Any help is appreciated.

edit:
PDF error is: The method or operation is not implemented.
DOCX error is: No filter defined

Windows Forms Application both are working. I'm considering getting the output from a Windows Forms/Console application.

Comment: Well, should have thought of this, the applications target platform was set at x32, IFilters are installed as x64.

The local webserver (visual studio 2010) won't start my app anymore because of the x64 change, but the live-server is working with .doc and .docx now.

Comment: Any news? I have the same problem now with pdf ifilter now.